# jQuery: Select only a class containing a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm currently using this to get the class for a specific bit of HTML on the page:

```
$(this).parent("div").attr('class')
```

But that `div` has multiple classes: `current_status status_billed`

My end goal here is to grab the class that starts with `status_` and replace it with a different class name.

So using my `.parent()` function above, I'm able to select the div I need, but I then need to remove the `status_billed` class and replace it with, for example, `status_completed` (or a number of other class names).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Select `div`s that have the `status_billed` class:

```
$(this).parent('div.status_billed')
```

Select `div`s whose `class` attribute contains `status_`:

```
$(this).parent('div[class*=status_]')
```

That's about the best you'll get with [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You can do better using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$(this).parent('div').filter(function ()
{
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++)
    {
        if (classes[i].slice(0,7) === 'status_')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

---

...but I'm not sure why you're doing all this - [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) returns at most 1 element. Did you mean [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) or [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents)?

Comment: Ah that's a good call, thanks.  I just deleted my post so he doesn't waste time going that route.

Comment: You can also use return classes[i]; instead of return true; to return the actual status_xxxx.

Comment: @Thomas: that's not how jQuery's `filter()` works. `"For each element, if the function returns true, the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded."`

Comment: Not sure I did a good job explaining myself. I'm using `parent()` to select the parent div of the element I'm currently working in. I don't need to return all the divs with that class. I can select the div I need fine, but I ultimately am trying to see what the name of the class is that starts with `status_` as it can be a number of different names.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Right you are, my memory served me badly :(. Thanks for the correction though...

Comment: @Azee you're very welcome. Just remember it's all in the docs! http://api.jquery.com