# Count divs by a part of a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I count divs which has the `_` inside a div?

e.g.

```
<div id="abc">
   <div class="_fruits">Fruits</div>
   <div class="flowers_yellow">Yellow Flowers</div>
   <div class="veggies">Veggies</div>
</div>
```

output should be 2

I know how to count divs by a class.

```
var countDIVS = $('._fruits').length;
```

but how do I count divs by a part of a class name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**attribute contains**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

```
$('#abc [class*="_"]').length
```

Comment: thanks. how do I specifically count inside of div `#abc`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106958/jquery-select-only-a-class-containing-a-string - here explanied ;)

Comment: Like this `$('#abc [class*="_"]').length`

Comment: @Becky, just prepend like `'#abc [class*="_"]'`

Comment: to count just DIVS with _ in class name within #abc, it would actually be $('#abc div[class*="_"]').length